# Issues with loading excel in Anaconda python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I just installed entire package of Anaconda3 (64-bit) on windows.I installed pandas in the current environment but I am finding difficulty with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.ExcelFile('172 Test Cases Design.xlsx')
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  data = pd.ExcelFile('172 Test Cases Design.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\rashmi_singh1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 257, in __init__
  self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Users\rashmi_singh1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
  packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook
  with open(filename, "rb") as f:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '172 Test Cases 
  Design.xlsx'
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Read the python docs in regards to paths and co. Your file is simply not found. (easy solution: absolute path). It's not a pandas problem.

Comment: **FileNotFoundError**, the log is as clear as it gets!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the excel file is in the same folder with your `.py`?

And one more thing: isn't the syntax supposed to be `pd.ExcelFile.parse`?

Comment: Thanks...it was the problem with the location of file. pd.Excelfile() also works,it is just for loading the entire excel workbook

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the info :D